# CORS With Enable OPTIONS Header on ASP Net Core 5 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, kestrel

I already have read all similar questions over here on StackO, and many others links and most of them are related to Core 2 and 3. Also have read all the [MS documentation for CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and still couldn't understand what is going wrong. So I would ask to read carefully what I'm going to write and watch all the evidences I do have.

On my environment I do have an Id Server 4 app running on Kestrel to handle auths and for this server I already have CORS working fine, also on my Id Server Clients I do have my ClientScopes related to my Client (Angular app).

#### Id Server 4 confg below:

[image]

#### Id Server is being called fine from my localhost app and working fine:

[image]
[image]

#### But when I do call my another web api (rede-dev), I'm facing a CORS issue:

[image]

#### Trying GET verb enforcing Origin header from Postman, it does work fine because it does not preflight the request:

[image]

#### But if I try OPTIONS, I cant see my OPTIONS verb on my responde header and I having a 405:

[image]

#### Startup.cs

So I made all the Startup.cs asked config based on MS docs also accordingly to [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order) and still not working.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                //builder.WithMethods("POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "OPTIONS");
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.WithHeaders("Authorization");
            });
        });

        //Json
        services.AddControllers();
        //services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

        //Log
        Serilog.Core.Logger serilog = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration).CreateLogger();
```

And

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
            }
        });
    }
```

What I am missing over here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try to remove builder.WithHeaders("Authorization");

Comment: @Sergey tried removing builder.WithHeaders("Authorization"); and have the same result.

Comment: Also tried to toggle RequireHttpsMetadata and nothing change. But I didn't try to set that to "true" and call from Angular App under HTTPS. Should I?

Comment: I don't have time to write this up as an answer just now, but the reason you are getting a 405 response to the OPTIONS request from Postman is because ASP.Net requires that at least the `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Origin` headers be specified for such a request when the CORS middleware is handling it (you have the latter but not the former).

Comment: ... Since you're using GET and that is generally considered a "safe" operation, the browser will issue it without pre-flight OPTIONS checks. So I'm guessing the error is stemming from some other issue (i.e. an unhandled exception), and CORS policy on the browser is just masking the issue. I'm not sure the default CORS middleware will include headers on 500 responses.

Comment: @PaulWheeler I was thinking about that so I tried UseExceptionHandler to see the error. So I would ask what error do you think could possible be to happens only when I am calling from localhost app (using OPTIONS in this case)?  And how could I get this error on server side?

Comment: @AndrewPaes that's a good question, I'm not sure. It might be helpful to see the client code that you're using to generate the request. You could also use a debugging proxy (I use https://www.charlesproxy.com/ but https://www.telerik.com/fiddler is also popular) so that we can see exactly what the request and response look like. So far I haven't been able to reproduce something that looks like your issue.

Comment: @PaulWheeler you are right, the error was elsewhere and could get reading the Kestrel log. Please, post your statement as answer so I'll comment below showing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this syntax

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

Comment: I already tried this one and still doesn't work.

Comment: Pls try again. Just copy and paste

Comment: ok, I just did copy and paste. Still the same error.

Comment: What Is the same error ? Method is not allowed?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same one.

Comment: can you post pls the action are you trying to call ( just a header) and how do you call this?

Comment: On my post you can see that on second print where i try with options verb.

Answer (score 1):

@PaulWheeler on comments above said  on comments above: *The reason you are getting a 405 response to the OPTIONS request from Postman is because ASP.Net requires that at least the 'Access-Control-Request-Method' and 'Origin' headers be specified for such a request when the CORS middleware is handling it (you have the latter but not the former). Since you're using GET and that is generally considered a "safe" operation, the browser will issue it without pre-flight OPTIONS checks. So I'm guessing the error is stemming from some other issue (i.e. an unhandled exception), and CORS policy on the browser is just masking the issue. I'm not sure the default CORS middleware will include headers on 500 responses.*

After Paul point me out the possible error, I did further investigation on my Kestrel logs as below:
[image]

After I few researchs I could figure out my problem was my certificate.
[image]

I was using one certificate for each app, instead oh that I should share the Id Server Certificate with others apps.

Tnx Paul,